# Can't build hzk (haskell zookeeper) with nix in stack project

Tags: haskell, apache-zookeeper, nix, nixos

I'm trying to port my employer's large haskell stack project to nix and it's barfing over `zookeeper_mt`. In stack.yaml I enabled the nix build and already added a few nix packages like zlib to cure build errors, but even with zookeeper_mt, I get:

```
hzk                             > configure
hzk                             > Configuring hzk-2.1.0...
hzk                             > Warning: 'ghc-options: -rtsopts' has no effect for libraries. It should only
hzk                             > be used for executables.
hzk                             > build
hzk                             > Preprocessing library for hzk-2.1.0..
hzk                             > /run/user/1000/stack-4c469d140762b8b0/hzk-2.1.0/CApi.hsc:76:10: fatal error: zookeeper.h: No such file or directory
hzk                             > compilation terminated.
hzk                             > compiling .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/Database/Zookeeper/CApi_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
hzk                             > command was: /nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/bin/cc -c .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/Database/Zookeeper/CApi_hsc_make.c -o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/Database/Zookeeper/CApi_hsc_make.o -fuse-ld=gold -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=808 -Dlinux_BUILD_OS=1 -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH=1 -Dlinux_HOST_OS=1 -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH=1 -I/usr/include/zookeeper -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qsarmp3rsyvhb7m22xl0fdpsnaf3lv6b-pcre-8.44-dev/include -I/nix/store/87w0n6hix0had2lp58i5rgmrr5dn3ghf-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/include -I/nix/store/v1v3flnwxs3n5lhfrfrs16rcygjzzhmy-zookeeper-3.4.13/include -I/nix/store/grng8b5wmrppx2rmcsqkmjyq23bj1j38-zookeeper_mt-3.4.13/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/usr/include/zookeeper -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qsarmp3rsyvhb7m22xl0fdpsnaf3lv6b-pcre-8.44-dev/include -I/nix/store/87w0n6hix0had2lp58i5rgmrr5dn3ghf-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/include -I/nix/store/v1v3flnwxs3n5lhfrfrs16rcygjzzhmy-zookeeper-3.4.13/include -I/nix/store/grng8b5wmrppx2rmcsqkmjyq23bj1j38-zookeeper_mt-3.4.13/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/autogen -I.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/global-autogen -include .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qsarmp3rsyvhb7m22xl0fdpsnaf3lv6b-pcre-8.44-dev/include -I/nix/store/87w0n6hix0had2lp58i5rgmrr5dn3ghf-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qsarmp3rsyvhb7m22xl0fdpsnaf3lv6b-pcre-8.44-dev/include -I/nix/store/87w0n6hix0had2lp58i5rgmrr5dn3ghf-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/home/ad/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/dd8fbb08ccfb9e77e9ffdb798576edd8f70b7edca799105b5bc2de70a44535a1/8.8.3/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.8.3/vector-0.12.1.2-AWRYcz9jfa25Avs2q9Jg9V/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/time-1.9.3/include -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/home/ad/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/dd8fbb08ccfb9e77e9ffdb798576edd8f70b7edca799105b5bc2de70a44535a1/8.8.3/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.8.3/primitive-0.7.0.1-CN4ea3Jrhra6yENuqrDg51/include -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qsarmp3rsyvhb7m22xl0fdpsnaf3lv6b-pcre-8.44-dev/include -I/nix/store/87w0n6hix0had2lp58i5rgmrr5dn3ghf-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qsarmp3rsyvhb7m22xl0fdpsnaf3lv6b-pcre-8.44-dev/include -I/nix/store/87w0n6hix0had2lp58i5rgmrr5dn3ghf-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/in9vak3zphkx9c635iz639iabgrib2fl-postgresql-11.8/include -I/nix/store/qsarmp3rsyvhb7m22xl0fdpsnaf3lv6b-pcre-8.44-dev/include -I/nix/store/87w0n6hix0had2lp58i5rgmrr5dn3ghf-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/nix/store/fn0kwfwaf53638xm37wl94la8dxlbjaq-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/bytestring-0.10.10.0/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/pj43dfd5k4zb0ivafkyqpr1blzd616ry-git-2.27.0/include -I/nix/store/za1rr3fxmgfbfl6nbigqi819m3m7nkgi-gcc-wrapper-9.3.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0/include -I/nix/store/00lmw45jlcm9ln2vi1rxxdz7cblwk3y6-gmp-6.2.0-dev/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/integer-gmp-1.0.2.0/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/include -I/nix/store/l9xqrgxn4z795jivmrmjyanlb6jjq66k-libffi-3.3-dev/include -I/nix/store/qqra09ff0q8vwqicjs20fn1rvn00k6fy-ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/include/
```

I can see in `nix-shell -p zookeeper_mt` that zookeeper.h ends up in `${zookeeper}/include/zookeeper/`, but that's just like the ubuntu package which also has this zookeeper subdirectory of /usr/include, and the project works fine in a non-nix stack build with that ubuntu package installed.

I see in that error message `-I/nix/store/grng8b5wmrppx2rmcsqkmjyq23bj1j38-zookeeper_mt-3.4.13/include` without the extra `/zookeeper` but I'm not sure which bit of the system is responsible for that or how to fix it cos I'm very new to nix. Is it the nix package's fault, stack's, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hzk.cabal` has lines like this

```
  include-dirs:        /usr/include/zookeeper
```

Which is a nice help for FHS-compliant systems, as long as the system distribution includes the zookeeper library. A local installation in `/usr/local` or `/opt/*` will result in the same problem.

Nixpkgs solves it like this https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a8a0dfa047d9a96f832ff2be30d004ad5544bd7e/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/configuration-nix.nix#L117-L120 but that doesn't translate to Stack.

To make it work in stack, we can use its nix-shell integration.

`stack.yaml`:

```
nix:
  packages: [] # Note that specifying both packages: and a shell-file: results in an error.
  shell-file: stack-shell.nix
```

`stack-shell.nix`:

```
{ghc}:
let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
# (side note)
# If you're pinning nixpkgs, You should probably set
# NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=... in your real `shell.nix`
# because that's where stack gets its ghc.
in
pkgs.haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "myEnv";
  buildInputs = [ pkgs.zookeeper_mt ];
  shellHook = ''
    NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE="-I ${pkgs.zookeeper_mt}/include/zookeeper $NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE"
  '';
}
```